# Wordpress подключается скрипты в Админке

Tags: wordpress

Проблема в следующем в теме вордпрес стили подключаются в админке хотя в `functions.php` вот такой экшн:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', theme_style());
function theme_style(){
        wp_enqueue_style('google-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext', $ver, 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('reset', get_template_directory_uri() . "/media/reset.css");
        wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri(), $ver, 'all');
        wp_enqueue_style('mobile-media', get_template_directory_uri() . "/media/media.css", $ver, 'screen');
    }
```

Не могу понять почему.

Comment: Не должно... Попробуй поискать такое слово `admin_enqueue_scripts`. Может где еще что-то подключается

Comment: Ну да, судя по коду - все правильно, не должны они в админке подключаться, копайте дальше

Comment: add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', theme_style()); функция должна быть строкой